# C# Reducing numbers in scientific notation from E+### to E+##

Tags: c#

Using .ToString("E4") prints a number like 1.2345E+012.

How can I make it print one less number in the exponential part.  In other words, print 1.2345E+12.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom format string with the `E` indicator, which takes the minimum number of digits:

```
double value = 1234567890000;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.####E+0"));
// 1.2346E+12
```

Comment: Why exactly does the `+0` part work? How does the compiler know that it should insert the exponent there?

Comment: @MetaColon The compiler doesn't know that, the implementation of `ToString` does.  And it knows that because it's just part of the specification for [that particular format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierExponent).

Answer (score 0):

You could always store '.ToString("E4")' in a string called "output". Then print "output" character by character until you read a "+" character in "output".  Don't print the next character if it's a "0", keep checking for "0"s until you reach something that does not equal (!=) a "0" character and then print the last characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try that code:

```
        var number = 1234567890000;
        var exponential = number.ToString("E4");
        var splitted = exponential.Split('+');
        var result = splitted.Length == 2 ? $"{splitted[0]}+{Convert.ToInt32(splitted[1])}" : exponential;
```

It takes the number, evaluates the exponential string and removes all leading zeros.

This is done by splitting at the + (if there is one, otherwise it's not neccessary and there won't be any leading zeros) and converting the string, of which the zero shall get removed, to a number. As numbers aren't stored with leading zeros, converting it back to a string removes the leading zeros.

If you want to prevent cases where `E+0` is written at the end, check the converted string for 0 and if so use the first part of the splitted string without the last character.